# How does mutability affect the lifetime of `self` in the following method implementations?

Tags: immutability, rust, lifetime

In the following case, why does the implementation of `get_foos_mut` for `B` give a lifetime error while the implementation of `get_foos` works fine?

```
trait Foo {
    fn get_foos<'a>(&'a self) -> Vec<&'a Foo> { Vec::new() }
    fn get_foos_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Vec<&'a mut Foo> { Vec::new() }
    fn hello(&self) { println!("Hello!") }
}

struct A { i: int }
impl Foo for A { fn hello(&self) { println!("Hello {}!", self.i) } }

struct B { foos: Vec<A> }
impl Foo for B {
    fn get_foos<'a>(&'a self) -> Vec<&'a Foo> {
        Vec::from_fn(self.foos.len(), |i| self.foos.get(i) as &Foo) // This is fine.
    }
    fn get_foos_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Vec<&'a mut Foo> {
        Vec::from_fn(self.foos.len(), |i| self.foos.get_mut(i) as &mut Foo) // This gives an error?
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = B { foos: vec![A { i: 1 }] };
    for foo in b.get_foos().iter() {
        foo.hello();
    }
}
```

This is the error as given by the playpen:

```
<anon>:17:43: 17:52 error: lifetime of `self` is too short to guarantee its contents can be safely reborrowed
<anon>:17         Vec::from_fn(self.foos.len(), |i| self.foos.get_mut(i) as &mut Foo)
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
<anon>:16:59: 18:6 note: `self` would have to be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 16:58...
<anon>:16     fn get_foos_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Vec<&'a mut Foo> {
<anon>:17         Vec::from_fn(self.foos.len(), |i| self.foos.get_mut(i) as &mut Foo)
<anon>:18     }
<anon>:17:9: 17:76 note: ...but `self` is only valid for the call at 17:8
<anon>:17         Vec::from_fn(self.foos.len(), |i| self.foos.get_mut(i) as &mut Foo)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

NOTE: I've noticed that `B`'s `get_foos_mut` will work if written like this:

```
fn get_foos_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Vec<&'a mut Foo> {
    let mut vec: Vec<&'a mut Foo> = Vec::with_capacity(self.foos.len());
    for foo in self.foos.mut_iter() { vec.push(foo); }
    vec
}
```

Why does the implementation work in this case and not in the `Vec::from_fn(...)` version above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `&mut` pointer has to be unaliased, that is, there can be no other reference/pointer/path by which you can read/write the data if you want to mutate via an `&mut`. When you call `self.foos.get_mut(i)`, `get_mut` acts like a black-box to the compiler, it can't tell what data is being borrowed, so it has to assume that the whole `Vec` is borrowed, due to the signature (which connects the return value to the `self` object via lifetimes)

```
fn get_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, index: uint) -> &'a mut T
```

or else someone could make aliasing `&mut` pointers: e.g.

```
let a = self.foos.get_mut(0);
let b = self.foos.get_mut(0);
```

[The `mut_iter` implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/slice.rs#L882-L901) uses `unsafe` internally, but it is carefully written to have a safe interface, that is, there is no way to use `mut_iter` to get aliasing `&mut` pointers (without `unsafe`) because it yields each mutable reference exactly once, in sequence.

FWIW, I would write those methods as `self.foos.iter().map(|x| x as &Foo).collect()` and `self.foos.mut_iter().map(|x| x as &mut Foo).collect()` rather than explicit `push`'s or `from_fn`'s

Comment: Excellent tip! I'm still learning about these fancy iterator tricks, thanks for the point in the right direction and the further explanation on the `mut_iter` implementation. Very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the signature of `Vec::get_mut`:

```
fn get_mut<T>(&'a mut self, index: uint) -> &'a mut T
```

That is, accessing even a single element mutably this way requires a `&mut` to the vector for as long as you keep the element reference. Because `&mut` may not alias (i.e. at all times there must only be a single `&mut` that reaches any given value) this means you can only get a single `&mut` out of `get_mut` at any given time. This conveniently prevents aliasing the elements of the vectors without any extra checks.

That's the semantic reasons (which would persist if you used an explicit loop instead of `from_fn`), the error message gives a different reason related to the currently-messy closure semantics. Don't worry about that one, digressing here would stray far from the core issue (and I'm not sure I would get it right).

The `mut_iter` variant works because it can guarantee that it only gives a reference to each element only *once* (per element), so it does just that. It can never introduce aliasing (though the compiler can't see that from the implementation so it uses `unsafe`).